# How to pass the SHEET_NAMES dynamically for XLS in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

there are two approached to pass sheet names value
1st approach:

```
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setParameter( JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, new String[] {"first","second","third"} );
```

cant we pass this value as parameter in java?

this way(1st approach) i am unable to follow because i am scheduling report for a specific date.
and passing few parameter inputs as well for the same report.

sample:

```
Util.getParamString(stringBuilder, "GENERATEDON", Date);//similarly few more params i am passing
```

2nd approach:

I am setting in the report properties like below (2nd approach):

```
Property Name = "net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.all"
Property Value = "first/second/third"
```

is there any chance to pass this property value as dynamic.

I have tried like below as not works for me

```
<line> 
   <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="1" height="1"> 
      <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{course_name}]]></propertyExpression> 
   </reportElement> 
</line>
```

Comment: If you are using Jasper Report version >4.5 `propertyExpression` on a reportElement should work, there is some other problem, try it on a textField (maybe it does not work on line) and that does not have negative y (y>=0), if it still does not work you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am using Jasper Report version-3.6

Comment: Time to upgrade?

Comment: i have tried with test field as well no luck                                          <textField>
<reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="1" height="1">
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{country_name}]]></propertyExpression>
</reportElement>
</textField>

Comment: You need version >4.5, upgrade or nothing

Comment: i can't change the version,i have to work on 3.6 only